# What changes were made that resulted in GTK3 Themes  broken?

Tags: gnome, themes

I'm not sure if this a bug as I didn't found anything conclusive, most Themes are broken in  Gnome 3.3.91 and had been broken ever since Gnome 3.3, However I see that the Ambiance and Radiance themes are not?.

What changes were made that only those Themes are looking fine but the rest aren't?

Note: This isn't exclusive to 12.04 I must add, this happens in 11.10 if one adds the Gnome 3 PPA.

[image]

Comment: The ppa comment is a clever way to sneak it in to mainline...but I won't vote on it either way.

Comment: screenshots are particularly useful for these kinds of questions.

Comment: @Jo-ErlendSchinstad From the screenshot you can see that.. everything is messed up, except the toolbar.

Comment: There's not mention of this in the Ubuntu launchpad bugs, in here , and on the forums..leads me to believe I'm the only one having this problem.

Comment: @UriHerrera: you're not. I too have this issue with most themes. I've been trying to figure out what went wrong as well.

Comment: @RolandTaylor That's a relief, I've read that we should just wait unitl Gnome 3.4 is released and then change the code for the themes accordingly.

Comment: @UriHerrera: oh? I get the problem with themes that claim to be compatible :(

Comment: @RolandTaylor I've only seen one theme that claims to be compatible, and it actually is, but other than that theme and Ambiance and Radiance everything is broken, even elementary, I did asked the author of that theme but since he isn't a native English speaker he couldn't tell me what he changed in his theme.

Comment: Just for kicks I took a look at /usr/share/themes recursive directory listing and by comparison, Ambiance and Radiance seem a LOT more thorough in addressing metacity/gtk-2.0/gtk-3.0/unity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

changes in the Gtk.CssProvider and various other changes are at fault:  See the answer to this question:  [No Items show in dash of gnome-shell when using "Axiom" Theme?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/119373/no-items-show-in-dash-of-gnome-shell-when-using-axiom-theme/119625#119625)  Gtk3 is currently in a state of flux so Gtk3 styles written for gnome-shell 3.2 (which is what most people were using a few months ago) are not current for 3.3 and 3.4  Unfortunately that means a lot of styles are unavailable or requires fixing in order to work.  My recommendation is to compare a working 3.4 style like malys unisex with any styles from 3.2 you wish to use and see where changes need to be made.

Comment: One of my favorites Zukitwo is broken, I've yet to take a look to try to fix it.