# No Items show in dash of gnome-shell when using "Axiom" Theme?

Tags: gnome, themes

I am using the [awesome Axiom Gnome-Shell theme](http://axiom613.deviantart.com/art/Axiom-Gnome-Shell-Theme-276676587) from Deviantart.

The theme works perfectly except for one issue, no items show up in the dash?

The actual items are there, e.g. if I type in something I know exists and then press enter it opens the program, there are simply no icons visible.

Why is this?

[image: Dash-no-items]

Yet after some more playing I have discovered some other funkyness, for example, if a lot of items are returned by the search you get:
[image: Dash-bugged-items]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There have been a lot of changes going on in Gtk3.  I don't know when you downloaded the theme, or what version of gnome-shell you are using, but this is almost certainly the result of those changes, particularly in styling.  You can hack around the css style sheet for the theme you downloaded or you can wait for the artist to update (or you to update depending).  From the website posted the artist updated 3/31 to support for gnome-shell 3.4.  From the looks of it you are still in gnome-shell 3.2 and this is probably the reason.  The relevant section of the gnome-shell.css sheet should be under Overview Apps, that being said it may be easiest to contact the Artist and ask if s/he has the old version.  I have a great 3.2 theme that is screwed up in the app overview in 3.4.